# Trouble displaying player Vector lives on stage

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, vector, flashdevelop, flash-cs6

Hey everyone so I am having some trouble displaying the player Vector lives in a Array added to the stage. When I first start my game the lives are added  correctly and when an enemy hits the player they are removed correctly but when I added a store where you can purchase an extra life I am getting a bug to where the vector lives are added to the stage but they dont remove when an enemy hits the player and they just are there.

in the constructor I have `nLives = 2; 
addPlayerLivesToStage();`

Here is the `addPlayerLivesToStage();` function as well as the `removePlayerLives();`

```
private function addPlayerLivesToStage():void 
    {

        var startPoint:Point = new Point((stage.stageWidth / 2) + 240, (stage.stageHeight / 2) - 180);
        var xSpacing:Number = 30;

        lives = new Vector.<Sprite>();

        for (var i:int = 0; i < nLives; i++)
        {
            var playerLives:mcPlayerLives = new mcPlayerLives();

            playerLives.x = startPoint.x + (xSpacing * i);
            playerLives.y = startPoint.y;

            addChild(playerLives);

            lives.push(playerLives);
            //aPlayerLivesArray.push(playerLives);
        }
    }



private function removePlayerLive():void
    {
        //Remove live from screen
        removeChild(lives[lives.length - 1]);
        lives[lives.length - 1] = null;
        lives.splice(lives.length - 1, 1);
    }
```

Now in my games ENTER.FRAME Loop I have the function `purchaseExtraLifeFunc();` that controls the Purchase and is supposed to add 1 life to the stage.

Like So:

```
private function purchaseExtraLifeFunc():void 
    {
        if (nCoins >= 5 && purchaseItem)
        {
            trace("purchase life");
            //remove coins from cost of purchase
            nCoins -= 5;
            updatecoinsTextScore();

            //add extra life
            nLives += 1;
            addPlayerLivesToStage();

        }
        else
        {
            purchaseItem = false;
        }
    }
```

as you can say I add 1 Live and call the addPlayerLivesToStage function.

THis is not working correctly and I'm all out of ideas if anyone could help me with this I would really aprreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few logic problems that could be the cause.

It looks like your `addPlayerLivesToStage` method ignores the fact that it could have been called before, and there could already be lives Sprites added to the stage. You then overwrite the lives Vector with a new Vector. So you don't have access to the previously added Sprites anymore.

I bet if you made the lives Sprites slightly transparent, you would see them stack over each other as you purchase more lives. Or to test, you could store a number that you increment every time you add a lives Sprite in your loop. And set the Y of the new sprite to this number. That way you would see all the Sprites you are adding.

To fix this, you want to remove all the lives Sprites at the beginning of your `addPlayerLivesToStage` function, because you are recreating them later in that function anyway.

EDIT*

The problem is still that the Sprites are not being cleaned up between addPlayerLivesToStage calls.

It is easier if you first use a container Spirte to hold all you life sprites. So add a private property to your class:

```
private var livesContainer:Sprite;
```

Then in you constructor, just set it up:

```
livesContainer = new Sprite();
livesContainer.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) + 240;
livesContainer.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - 180;
addChild(livesContainer);
```

The you can just add all the lives into this container.

I modified your addPlayerLivesToStage function to remove any left over life sprites at the end, and cleaned up the adding, so it does not add a life that is already added.

```
private function addPlayerLivesToStage():void 
{
    var xSpacing:Number = 30;

    // Add new life sprites if we need to.
    for (var i:int = lives.length; i < nLives; i++)
    {
        var playerLives:mcPlayerLives = new mcPlayerLives();
        playerLives.x = xSpacing * i;
        livesContainer.addChild(playerLives);
        lives.push(playerLives);
    }

    // Remove any life Sprites that are left over from last time.
    for (var j:int = lives.length - 1; j > nLives; j--)
    {
        var life:Sprite = lives[j]
        livesContainer.removeChild(life);
        lives.splice(j, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah you are right that is exactly what is happening and when my lives.length == 0 at my endGameFunction it ignores the extra live sprites on stage and they arent removed.  Okay so what exactly do you mean remove the lives sprites at the beginning of the function? Still kinda confused about that part. But thank you so much for the help so far I appreciate it.

Comment: I added the  lives = new Vector.<Sprite>();   to my constructor function and removed it from the addPlayerLivesToStage(); Function but that still didnt seem to fix the problem. Not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Interesting so with this new edit I would have to also update my removePlayerLive(); function correct? when an enemy hits the player to remove a live from the stage?

Comment: Yeah because for some reason whenever the player is hit by a hitTestObject it is not removing any lives from the array of sprites. I cant seem to get the removePlayerLives(); function to work correctly. any help?